# Change date color e format date in same field

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, extjs5

To format the date in a displayfield I use:

```
renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d-m-Y')
```

To change the date displayed color I use, for example:

```
renderer : function(val) {
     if (val) {
        return '<span style="color:' + '#CC6666' + ';">' + val + '</span>';
     }
     return val;
}
```

My problem is to use both simultaneously: the formatted date and change the color of the displayed date.

How to do this?

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jnj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a call to the formatter method:

```
renderer: function(val) {
    if (val) {
        return '<span style="color:#CC6666;">' + Ext.util.Format.date(val, 'd-m-Y') + '</span>';
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Thank Evan, works well. I tried with Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer, however, in this case, as you explained, the right is Ext.util.Format.date. I edited my fiddle with right solution.